# ASP.NET Repeater question

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater control and under the ItemTemplate, I have Image control. Anyway the old

How can I set the ImageUrl programatically?

Anyway, the old html code I have was like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <img src="<%# Eval("ImageSource") %>" alt="" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

But I want to check if the image exists in directory or not then I can setup with temp image.

I have a code but .. it's not really working so there's no sense of showing it here. Can you guys help me? Should I use ItemCreated or ItemDataBound event?

Comment: It's great to ask here in stackoverflow, you can get the responses and answer immediately, unlike in msdn forums. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the xml side in the template, you need to call a method directly.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImg" ImageUrl='<%# MyImageUrlFunction(Eval("DataFieldName").ToString()); %>' />
```

You need a corresponding method in the code behind defined publicly:

```
public string MyImageUrlFunction(string field) 
{
    // put some logic here to determine url
    return imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Error 4 The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: ok I got it working. But there's an error in your code. There shouldn't be a semicolon at the end :) but thanks Joel!

Comment: @Nullstr1ng - sorry about that. I didn't have access to my IDE and I've been hopping back and forth between vb and c# so my ; finger is a little trigger happy.

Answer (score 2):

In your `ItemDataBound`, do something like:

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage)e.Item.FindControl("img");

    string imageUrl = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ImageSource");
    if (File.Exists(imageUrl))
        img.Src = imageUrl;
}
```

That's `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage`, `System.Web.UI.DataBinder` and `System.IO.File`.

Answer (score 1):

ItemDataBound.  You can get the control reference through the current item's findcontrol event, and then check to see that the image exists.  You can get the file path using Server.MapPath("~/images/test.png"), and then if it doesn't, inject your own.

You can also use a public method that the client-side markup can call, pass in the URL, and provide a default if it doesn't exist.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# System.IO.File.Exists(Eval("ImageSourceProperty").ToString()) ? Eval("ImageSourceProperty").ToString() : TemporaryImagePath %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Error 4 The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

for the Error

> The server tag is not well formed

You should remove extra space in your code!

```
<%# System.IO.File......%>
should be <%#System.IO.File......%>
```